# What is the proper way to get private data from a MySQL database to an iOS app?

Tags: ios, mysql, swift

I am currently developing an app for a friend's business (so it's clear that I am not a professional developer and he's not going to get the perfect app). He needs the app to display and be able to interact with data from a MySQL database. I have already tried to find a way to do this but they mostly include a PHP script that just generates a json document which the app can then read. I cannot do that because the data includes customer information that can't just be accessible like that without some form of authentication from the app. The app will only be used by employees at work and on specific devices so storing the data locally is not a problem. Is there maybe a way to create a local cache of the database and then work with that? I would also be open to use other database software that can handle spreadsheet-like data.

Thanks in advance for any response!

Comment: If you can convert mySQL database to SQLite one, you’ll be able to use it on iOS in a regular way of working with the database. You will even be able to set a password protection for it.

Comment: At the same time, if the data is sensitive private information, it is not secure to ship it together with the app to the App Store, even with the password protection.

Comment: Yes, you can create SQLite database and include that in your project and it can be included with the app that you install on the devices. But it doesn’t seem prudent to jump to every device having it’s own unique, local copy of the database simply because you don’t want to address the authentication question. You really should just solve authentication. If doing PHP, I might advise Laravel framework, getting you out of writing your own authentication subsystem. Or consider Firebase. But I wouldn’t advise using local copies of a db just because you don’t want to deal with authentication.

Comment: @Rob Thank you! If that is the best way to do it I will probably end up using PHP with some sort of authentication. I might also look into Firebase. When I was talking about local copies, I meant it as more of a cache and not unique databases for every decide that are shipped with the app but in hindsight I'm not sure how I imagined that working any better.

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk Thanks for the replies! I wasn't planning on shipping this app to any public space so that would not be an issue, however I need to be able to sync the local database with the server. I realized I worded that a bit badly in my original post.

Comment: If you need to sync it, check RestKit - it’s a framework to store remote objects, delivered from a backend in JSON format, in SQLite database.

Comment: Yeah, if you’re downloading/caching copies of the database, then you have to solve the authentication question, anyway. Generally we only do the caching/synchronizing of databases to solve connectivity issues, offline access, etc.

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk Thank you for the recommendation, I will take a look at it!

Comment: @Rob Yeah, I just didn't include it in the original post because it was more of a nice-to-have but not a must because my friend doesn't have any control over the Wi-Fi quality there and said it is pretty inconsistent. The majority of the data could be cached and only has to be updated every day or so. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your app going to get JSON data through PHP API. In that case, PHP API should encrypt the JSON data and your app will decrypt it. If you want to protect your data on users device, one of the option to use cipher SQLite.

You can any use symmetric or asymmetric encryption technique to encrypt the API response.

Here is good post to read.

https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/symmetric-vs-asymmetric-encryption-what-are-differences